# 2 240v AC parallel solid state relays on 2 resistive loads off of L1 and L2

Tags: parallel, solid-state-relay, diagram

My hope is to keep the solid state relays as cool as possible by dividing the circuit load, it is duty cycled and will run up to 72 hours.

[image: divided 240v load circuit control]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I need to know if this wiring configuration will work with AC voltage and meet my objective?

Answer (score 1):

"As cool as possible" isn't an answerable statement (heatsink? Bigger heatsink?
Heatsink with fan? Cold plate? Cold plate with peltier? Stirling cryocooler? Liquid nitrogen? Liquid helium?), so I'll assume you mean "within operational parameters". The non-answer answer is "whatever your SSR's datasheet says".

On the face of it, 20A on a 25A relay sounds reasonable but SSRs have several heavy caveats. A 25A AC relay will have a thyristor voltage drop of ~1.3V, so you're making 26W at 20A; a heatsink is absolutely essential. Your datasheet will tell you how big the heatsink needs to be in K/W. If it doesn't (maybe because it came from Amazon/ebay/alibaba), then you should find a new SSR. You must scrupulously observe the mounting instructions for thermal interface material, orientation, and screw torque. 4800W 240V loads aren't to be trifled with. If they are inductive, then they need to be snubbed/suppressed; SSRs do not handle inductive kick well.

Also, the control lines should be paralleled and include a resistor or other current limiting device if not already built in.

Answer (score 0):

It somewhat depends on the solid-state relays.

Triac based SSRs have an inherent 1.4-2V inefficiency, so you'll get 1.4 to 2w of heat produced by the relay for every amp. so splitting the load here will only give a slight reductuion in total heating

MOSFET based SSRs have only I<sup>2</sup>C heating and so splitting the load in two will halve total heating, a definiate win.  but just switching from Triac to MOSFET will also reduce heating a lot.